# Is there a term for the navbar with a stripe below it?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know if there is a term for those navbars with an stripe of solid colour below it, and animates when hovering. I find it very pleasing to look at.

Currently using: https://steelseries.com/
http://prntscr.com/bvaz2u

Does it use any Javascript? Is it easy to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is duplicate, here is a CSS only solution:

```
.navbar {
  max-height: 50px;
}

.navbar-nav>li:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: ease .25s;
}

.navbar-nav>li:hover:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #E74C3C;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Working Codepen example:

http://codepen.io/charliebeckstrand/pen/YWaWzp

To answer your question, JavaScript is not necessarily and I do not believe there is an official term for it. "Animate Border Bottom" is an appropriate description though.